# How to provide Store in component which doesn't has a default AppState from forRoot() jnitalization

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have question about NGRX store, and providing it to components.

Currently my app architecture is like this:
app.module -> `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers})`

```
export interface AppState {
  user: User.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  user: userReducer,
};
```

other feature module -> `StoreModule.forFeature('feature', featureReducers),`

In this approach everything is working fine and I can provide store to components like this:

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<AppState>,
) {}
```

Now I want to stop using default AppState. I want to remove `forRoot` in app.module and using only the features modules with `forFeature`.
In this situation how can I provide Store to components? What should I pass into `Store<???>`?

Answer (score 0):

The store always contains the whole state object. When you inject the store, the generic is purely for type checking/safety. In other words, you can do:

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<FeatureState>,
) {}
```

Also, make sure you leave the `forRoot` import in your `AppModule`, you need this once in your application to wire up NgRx internally. While doing this you can pass an empty reducer object.

```
StoreModule.forRoot({}, [])
```